# Five equal columns in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I want to have 5 equal columns on a page I am building and I can't seem to understand how the 5 column grid is being used here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20120416024539/http://domain7.com/mobile/tools/bootstrap/responsive

Is the five column grid being demonstrated above part of the twitter bootstrap framework?

Comment: You're looking at a very old version of the bootstrap. Are you looking to have a 5-column "responsive" grid on the (latest, i hope) bootstrap?

Comment: I just realized that.The one stated is v1.3.0 and the current is 2.0.2.The latest version is a 12-column grid meaning i can have 2,3,4 and 6 equal columns.What i was asking is,if it would be possible to have 5 equal columns without having to change a lot of things.

Comment: you can, yes, but it will require heavy modifications to some of the grid elements and also the responsive grid elements. Is your site responsive at all? It would be a bit easier to come up with an answer that way, otherwise it would be a lot of code.

Comment: Yes,the site is responsive but i would have to modify the grid elements too not the responsive part only imho.

Comment: What im saying is that if the grid elements are modified to accommodate a 5-grid setup then the responsive feature will also have to  be heavily modified to support them.

Comment: I am having some success* with .container.one-fifth.column { width:17%; } although i am expecting  something aweful to take my breath away.17.87847% too.

Comment: I added .spanfifth {
  width: 17.89987%;
} to bootstrap.css and it works even when i resize the browser.

Comment: 18.298% would work for one fifth but when you wan't four fifth and the other fifths to work,something  below or above 17% is proving problematic.

Comment: This is one of the things that Bootstrap seem to ignore totally, Foundation for example have created a block-grid that can have any number of columns that are equal with of course the ability to change how many to show in one row for different breakpoints [Check The docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) What I highly advice is not to try to extend Bootstrap on this one, just go on with creating your own layout that generalises having any odd number of columns per row, you can cheat from this Foundation Module as a starter and fit it to your needs.

Comment: **Bootstrap 4** - Simply use auto-layout. It requires no extra CSS or SASS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42226652/171456

Answer (score 436, accepted):

Use five divs with a class of span2 and give the first a class of offset1.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2 offset1"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
</div>
```

Voila!
Five equally spaced and centered columns.

---

In bootstrap 3.0, this code would look like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

---

### UPDATE

Since bootstrap 4.0 uses Flexbox by default:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't go on full width. it's nice though

Comment: The solution I posted goes full width and creates 5 equal columns: [HERE IS THE ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22799354/1799136).

Comment: Doesn't go full width like the answer @fizzix provides below. Makes an unwanted margin on both sides, like so - http://jsfiddle.net/wdo8L1ww/

Comment: for those of you using less/sass with bootstrap 3, check [@lightswitch05 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21142019/1859114)

Comment: **Bootstrap 4** 5 cols (full-width) requires no CSS or SASS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42226652/171456

Answer (score 594):

## For Bootstrap 4

Bootstrap 4 now uses flexbox by default, so you get access to its magical powers straight out of the box. Check out the [auto layout columns](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) that dynamically adjust width depending on how many columns are nested.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      1 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      2 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      3 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      4 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      5 of 5
   </div>
</div>
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k1hon1o2/3/)

---

## For Bootstrap 3

A fantastic **full width** 5 columns layout with Twitter Bootstrap was created [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140410144231/http://www.wearesicc.com/quick-tips-5-column-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap/).

This is by far the most advanced solution since it works seamlessly with Bootstrap 3. It allows you to re-use the classes over and over again, in pair with the current Bootstrap classes for responsive design.

**CSS:**
Add this to your global stylesheet, or even to the bottom of your `bootstrap.css` document.

```
.col-xs-5ths,
.col-sm-5ths,
.col-md-5ths,
.col-lg-5ths {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-xs-5ths {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

**Put it to use!**
For example, if you want to create a div element that behaves like a five column layout on medium screens and like two columns on smaller ones, you just need to use something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5ths col-xs-6">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sct3j/283/) - Expand the frame to see the columns become responsive.

[**ANOTHER DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fx2k7/91/) - Incorporating the new `col-*-5ths` classes with others such as `col-*-3` and `col-*-2`. Resize the frame to see them all change to `col-xs-6` in responsive view.

Comment: Calling them `col-*-15` might be confusing. It seems to imply they’re part of a 15-column grid system, which they’re not.

Comment: Yes I understand that, although I was not to sure what else to call them since `col-*-3` does not mean that there are 3 columns across, so `col-*-5` would be confusing too. Do you have any naming recommendations @PaulD.Waite?

Comment: I know what you mean, I couldn’t think of a good alternative.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I added a little note to my answer to let people know.

Comment: `col-*-15` is fine with me, but `col-*-5ths` might be a slightly less confusing column name. That's what I'm using so that my other developers don't come to me confused.

Comment: @Mordred - Great idea! I'll edit my answer to go with that :)

Comment: Why do you make them relative positioned when they're already floated? Is there a browser bug you're working around or something?

Comment: Hey @scragar - If you view the styling for all Bootstrap's current column classes, you will notice that they all contain `position:relative; min-height: 1px; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;`. Basically, the code I posted is just extending on this so that they match Bootstrap's built in styling EXACTLY. I then apply a width of `20%` so that 5 equal columns can fit across the page. Very simple :)

Comment: very useful - thanks. I had to change the padding from 10px to 15px for the columns to align left and right with content in standard 12 column bootstrap rows, though. Typo in css above?

Comment: why you need to write media query? I think we can write `.col-xs-5ths,
.col-sm-5ths,
.col-md-5ths,
.col-lg-5ths {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}`

Comment: This solution works fine for 5 columns. However it does not work properly in case one needs 5 columns for medium screen and 6 columns for large screen. Please consider revising the 1200px media as follows: @media (min-width: 1200px) { .col-lg-5ths { width: 20%; float: left; } .col-lg-2.col-md-5ths { width: 16.67%; } }

Comment: @MalayMondal - The media queries are **definitely** needed. If you use `col-lg-5ths`, and the screen is below 1200px, it'll be full width instead of `20%` since they referenced the `lg` class. Always keep in mind with Boostrap, it is "mobile first".

Comment: As long as there is 5ths it won't listen to any col-s, why?

Comment: @BojanKogoj - Can you please explain what you mean in further detail?

Comment: how about naming for 2/5 column ?
Or we should use :
col-md-1ths for 1/5 and col-md-2ths for 2/5, col-md-5ths for 5/5 = full width ?

Comment: Hey @Fizzix thanks for adding the Bootstrap 4 reference. But what about if I need to display the 5 columns only in ≥992px and <992px display each "element" in a full-width row.

in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ says: Equal-width columns can be broken into multiple lines, but there was a Safari flexbox bug that prevented this from working without an explicit `flex-basis` or `border`. /// But how can I achieve that behaviour that I want? could you help me, please?

Comment: I have posted it on a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858501/non-12-divisible-equal-columns-on-bootstrap-4

Answer (score 171):

For **Bootstrap 3**, if you want **full-width** and are using `LESS`, `SASS`, or something similar, all you have to do is make use of [Bootstrap's mixin functions](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less) `make-md-column`, `make-sm-column`, etc.

LESS:

```
.col-lg-2-4{
  .make-lg-column(2.4)
}
.col-md-2-4{
  .make-md-column(2.4)
}
.col-sm-2-4{
  .make-sm-column(2.4)
}
```

SASS:

```
.col-lg-2-4{
  @include make-lg-column(2.4)
}
.col-md-2-4{
  @include make-md-column(2.4)
}
.col-sm-2-4{
  @include make-sm-column(2.4)
}
```

Not only can you build **true full-width bootstrap column classes** using these mixins, but you can also build all the **related helper classes** like `.col-md-push-*`, `.col-md-pull-*`, and `.col-md-offset-*`:

LESS:

```
.col-md-push-2-4{
  .make-md-column-push(2.4)
}
.col-md-pull-2-4{
  .make-md-column-pull(2.4)
}
.col-md-offset-2-4{
  .make-md-column-offset(2.4)
}
```

SASS:

```
.col-md-push-2-4{
  @include make-md-column-push(2.4)
}
.col-md-pull-2-4{
  @include make-md-column-pull(2.4)
}
.col-md-offset-2-4{
  @include make-md-column-offset(2.4)
}
```

Other answers talk about setting `@gridColumns` which is perfectly valid, but that changes the core column width for all of bootstrap. Using the above mixin functions will add 5 column layout on top of the default bootstrap columns, so it will not break any 3rd party tools or existing styling.

Comment: Cleanest solution, as `2.4` is a 5th of 12 (`2.4*5=12`), works for Bootstrap 3 in a 12-columns grid.
Also applies to `make-xs`, `make-sm`, but it will not work combined to other standard col definitions (latest get priority)

Comment: I'm shocked at the comparatively few upvotes for this answer. It's by far the least hacky, using not only the same naming convention as other Bootstrap column classes, but also the same mixins Bootstrap uses to create its own columns, making it probably future-proof until Bootstrap 4, at the very least.

Comment: This is supposed to be the best answer. I have created a library (to include `offset`, `pull` and `push`) based on this for my own use. Feel free to [check it out](https://github.com/kennyki/bootstrap-5-columns)

Comment: As everyone has said, yes this is now the correct answer.  @Sherbrow said they "will not work combined to other standard col definitions" but this isn't because this solution is wrong in some way, its simply because 12%5 != 0.

Comment: I would recommend using `make-xs-column` mixin, because this size will work for all screen sizes.

Comment: Where do you add the mixin? Does this go right in the scss file?

Comment: @bjorkland yes this can go right into your scss file if you are already correctly importing bootstrap scss

Comment: Shoot, I'm not importing bootstrap...just linking to the CDN manually (building a site in Jekyll)

Comment: Thanks @lightswitch05 but what about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858501/non-12-divisible-equal-columns-on-bootstrap-4

Comment: Is there an updated solution for Bootstrap 4? These mixins dont seem to exist anymore

Comment: @Plog nothing extra is required for 5 column layout in bootstrap 4. See Fizzix's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22799354/912563) for an example for bootstrap 4

Comment: @lightswitch05 Unfortunately that wasn't suitable for me since I had a dynamic amount of columns. If I only had one column I still wanted it to be a 5th of the screen but using Fizzix's answer a single column would cover the whole screen. I managed to solve it using the new Bootstrap 4 mixin functions. I could update your answer to include this if you like?

Comment: @Plog please do, just make it clear its for boostrap 4

Answer (score 53):

**Bootstrap 5+ (update 2023)**

Bootstrap 5 now has the `row-cols-*` classes which make it easy to get 5 columns...

```
<div class="row row-cols-5">
    <div class="col"> </div>
    <div class="col"> </div>
    <div class="col"> </div>
    <div class="col"> </div>
...
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/oPOlbjs7XA)

---

**Bootstrap 4.1+ (update 2019)**

Here are 5 equal, full-width columns (**no extra CSS or SASS**) using the [auto-layout grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="col">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/MJTglTsq9h

This solution works because Bootstrap 4 is now flexbox. You can get the 5 columns to wrap within the same `.row` using a break such as `<div class="col-12"></div>` or `<div class="w-100"></div>` every 5 columns.

Also see: [Bootstrap - 5 column layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944691/bootstrap-5-column-layout?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Can't wait for it to be stable :)

Comment: Good but only works with rows of 5 elements. If you get more you are wrong.
See my enhenced fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/djibe89/ntq8h910/

Comment: That's why I explained you have to use the break every 5 columns. Your solution works but requires extra CSS.

Comment: Also consider adding `flex-nowrap` to the `.row` since the (automatic) columns could exceed the parent width.

Comment: Adding a col-12 to break lines is genius because you can hide it at other screen sizes. For example, `<div class="col-sm-12"></div>` will force them to be 5 items at larger screen sizes, but a normal list at smaller sizes.

Answer (score 32):

Below is a combo of @machineaddict and @Mafnah answers, re-written for Bootstrap 3 (working well for me so far):

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .fivecolumns .col-md-2, .fivecolumns .col-sm-2, .fivecolumns .col-lg-2  {
        width: 20%;
        *width: 20%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .fivecolumns .col-md-2, .fivecolumns .col-sm-2, .fivecolumns .col-lg-2 {
        width: 20%;
        *width: 20%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .fivecolumns .col-md-2, .fivecolumns .col-sm-2, .fivecolumns .col-lg-2 {
        width: 20%;
        *width: 20%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I place this and how do I use it?

Comment: @Serg 
1. Place it below/ after the Bootstrap css file
2. Add the .fivecolumns class to the .row, then nest five columns with the class .col[,-sm,-lg]-2

Comment: Does not go perfect full width in some cases.

Comment: Why is col-xs-2 not added to the declarations?

Comment: @ganders just an over sight; check out another answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap#answer-22799354

Answer (score 27):

Keep the original bootstrap with 12 columns, do not customize it. The only modification you need to make is some css **after** the original bootstrap responsive css, like this:

The following code has been tested for Bootstrap 2.3.2:

```
<style type="text/css">
/* start of modification for 5 columns */
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .fivecolumns .span2 {
        width: 18.297872340425532%;
        *width: 18.2234042553191494%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .fivecolumns .span2 {
        width: 17.9487179487179488%;
        *width: 17.87424986361156592%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .fivecolumns .span2 {
        width: 17.79005524861878448%;
        *width: 17.7155871635124022%;
    }
}
/* end of modification for 5 columns */
</style>
```

And the html:

```
<div class="row-fluid fivecolumns">
    <div class="span2">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Even though the span2 times 5 doesn't equal 12 columns, you get the idea :)

A working example can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/v3Uy5/6/

Answer (score 11):

In case you do no need the **exact** same width of columns you can try create 5-columns using nesting:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 column">Column 1</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 column">Column 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 column">Column 3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 column">Column 4</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 column">Column 5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DraggonZ/obrbmpes/)

The first two columns will have width equal 5/12 * 1/2 ~ 20.83%

The last three columns:  7/12 * 1/3 ~ 19.44%

Such hack gives the acceptable result in many cases and does not require any CSS changes (we're using only the native bootstrap classes).

Answer (score 9):

## Create a custom Bootstrap download for 5 column layout

Go to [Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html#variables) (or [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-basics)) customization page and set the following variables (don't input semicolons):

```
@gridColumns:           5;
@gridColumnWidth:       172px;
@gridColumnWidth1200:   210px;
@gridColumnWidth768:    128px;
@gridGutterWidth768:    21px;
```

Download your build. This grid would fit into default containers, preserving default gutter widths (almost).

**Note:** If you are using LESS, update `variables.less` instead.

Answer (score 7):

With flexbox http://output.jsbin.com/juziwu

```css
.flexrow {
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray; /*for debug*/
}
.flexrow > * {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1em;
  outline: auto green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexrow">
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...<br>..</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flexbox is better than bootstrap if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 6):

```
<div class="equal row-fluid">
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
</div>

.equal .span2 {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: that should be 

.equal .span2 {
    width: 20%;
}

Comment: ... and it's NOT working. each column, except the first one, has margin left.

Answer (score 6):

I voted up Mafnah's answer but looking at this again I'd suggest the following is better if you're keeping the default margins etc.

```
<div class="equal row-fluid">
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
</div>

.equal .span2 {
    width: 17.9%;
}
```

Comment: The actual width is **17.94872%** and it is not responsive, you will have to set a new margin for each column in all the @media queries.

Answer (score 6):

Create 5 elements with the class col-sm-2 and add to the first element also the class col-sm-offset-1

P.s. this will not be full width (it will be indented a little from the right and left of the screen)

The code should look something like this

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1"></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
```

Comment: This is the solution I chose for this issue. I believe this works well in bootstrap 3,4 and 5.

Answer (score 6):

## The best way

Only add **.row-cols-5** class to your row. so you have 5 div on each line.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-cols-5">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="col">5</div>
        <div class="col">6</div>
        <div class="col">7</div>
        <div class="col">8</div>
        <div class="col">9</div>
        <div class="col">10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use the responsive .row-cols-* classes to quickly set the number of columns that best render your content and layout. Whereas normal .col-* classes apply to the individual columns (e.g., .col-md-4), the row columns classes are set on the parent .row as a shortcut.

- row-cols-*
- row-cols-sm-*
- row-cols-md-*
- row-cols-lg-*
- row-cols-xl-*

You can also use the accompanying Sass mixin, row-cols():

```
.element {
  // Three columns to start
  @include row-cols(3);

  // Five columns from medium breakpoint up
  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    @include row-cols(5);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### For Bootstrap 5 or later

You can use the `row-cols-` class name.

ex: `row-cols-1`, `row-cols-5`, `row-cols-lg-5`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-5">
     // place your all cols here
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information read the [official docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#row-columns)

Answer (score 5):

## Bootstrap 4, variable number of columns per row

If you want to have *up to* five columns per row, so that fewer numbers of columns still only take up 1/5th of the row each, the solution is to use Bootstrap 4's [mixins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#mixins):

SCSS:

```
.col-2-4 {
    @include make-col-ready(); // apply standard column margins, padding, etc.
    @include make-col(2.4); // 12/5 = 2.4
}
.col-sm-2-4 {
    @include make-col-ready();
    @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
        @include make-col(2.4);
    }
}
.col-md-2-4 {
    @include make-col-ready();
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
        @include make-col(2.4);
    }
}
.col-lg-2-4 {
    @include make-col-ready();
    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
        @include make-col(2.4);
    }
}
.col-xl-2-4 {
    @include make-col-ready();
    @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
        @include make-col(2.4);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2-4">1 of 5</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2-4">2 of 5</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2-4">3 of 5</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2-4">4 of 5</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2-4">5 of 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2-4">1 of 2</div> <!-- same width as column "1 of 5" above -->
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2-4">2 of 2</div> <!-- same width as column "2 of 5" above -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**For Bootstrap 4.4+**

Use the brand new `row-cols-n` classes.

1. Add `row-cols-5` class to your `.row` div. No custom CSS needed.
2. See the 4.4 doc here for row-cols : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#row-columns

**For Bootstrap 4 versions prior to Bootstrap 4.4**

1. Copy CSS below (awesome CSS by Bootstrap authors) and add it to your project
2. Read the docs cited above to use it correctly.

   `.row-cols-1>*{-ms-flex:0 0 100%;flex:0 0 100%;max-width:100%}.row-cols-2>*{-ms-flex:0 0 50%;flex:0 0 50%;max-width:50%}.row-cols-3>*{-ms-flex:0 0 33.333333%;flex:0 0 33.333333%;max-width:33.333333%}.row-cols-4>*{-ms-flex:0 0 25%;flex:0 0 25%;max-width:25%}.row-cols-5>*{-ms-flex:0 0 20%;flex:0 0 20%;max-width:20%}.row-cols-6>*{-ms-flex:0 0 16.666667%;flex:0 0 16.666667%;max-width:16.666667%}@media (min-width:576px){.row-cols-sm-1>*{-ms-flex:0 0 100%;flex:0 0 100%;max-width:100%}.row-cols-sm-2>*{-ms-flex:0 0 50%;flex:0 0 50%;max-width:50%}.row-cols-sm-3>*{-ms-flex:0 0 33.333333%;flex:0 0 33.333333%;max-width:33.333333%}.row-cols-sm-4>*{-ms-flex:0 0 25%;flex:0 0 25%;max-width:25%}.row-cols-sm-5>*{-ms-flex:0 0 20%;flex:0 0 20%;max-width:20%}.row-cols-sm-6>*{-ms-flex:0 0 16.666667%;flex:0 0 16.666667%;max-width:16.666667%}}@media (min-width:768px){.row-cols-md-1>*{-ms-flex:0 0 100%;flex:0 0 100%;max-width:100%}.row-cols-md-2>*{-ms-flex:0 0 50%;flex:0 0 50%;max-width:50%}.row-cols-md-3>*{-ms-flex:0 0 33.333333%;flex:0 0 33.333333%;max-width:33.333333%}.row-cols-md-4>*{-ms-flex:0 0 25%;flex:0 0 25%;max-width:25%}.row-cols-md-5>*{-ms-flex:0 0 20%;flex:0 0 20%;max-width:20%}.row-cols-md-6>*{-ms-flex:0 0 16.666667%;flex:0 0 16.666667%;max-width:16.666667%}}@media (min-width:992px){.row-cols-lg-1>*{-ms-flex:0 0 100%;flex:0 0 100%;max-width:100%}.row-cols-lg-2>*{-ms-flex:0 0 50%;flex:0 0 50%;max-width:50%}.row-cols-lg-3>*{-ms-flex:0 0 33.333333%;flex:0 0 33.333333%;max-width:33.333333%}.row-cols-lg-4>*{-ms-flex:0 0 25%;flex:0 0 25%;max-width:25%}.row-cols-lg-5>*{-ms-flex:0 0 20%;flex:0 0 20%;max-width:20%}.row-cols-lg-6>*{-ms-flex:0 0 16.666667%;flex:0 0 16.666667%;max-width:16.666667%}}@media (min-width:1200px){.row-cols-xl-1>*{-ms-flex:0 0 100%;flex:0 0 100%;max-width:100%}.row-cols-xl-2>*{-ms-flex:0 0 50%;flex:0 0 50%;max-width:50%}.row-cols-xl-3>*{-ms-flex:0 0 33.333333%;flex:0 0 33.333333%;max-width:33.333333%}.row-cols-xl-4>*{-ms-flex:0 0 25%;flex:0 0 25%;max-width:25%}.row-cols-xl-5>*{-ms-flex:0 0 20%;flex:0 0 20%;max-width:20%}.row-cols-xl-6>*{-ms-flex:0 0 16.666667%;flex:0 0 16.666667%;max-width:16.666667%}}`

Answer (score 4):

Another way to enable 5 columns in Bootstrap 3 is to modify the 12 columns format used by default by Bootstrap. And then create a 20 columns grid (use customize on the Bootstrap website OR use the LESS/SASS version).

To customize on the bootstrap website, go to [Customize and Download](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page, update variable  `@grid-columns` from `12` to `20`. Then you will be able to create 4 as well as 5 columns.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap by default can scale up to 12 columns? This means if we want to create a 12-column layout of equal width, we would write inside div class="col-md-1" twelve times.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1"></div>    
<div class="col-md-2">1</div>
<div class="col-md-2">2</div>
<div class="col-md-2">3</div>
<div class="col-md-2">4</div>
<div class="col-md-2">5</div>
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with nesting and using a little css over-ride.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7 five-three">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      Column 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      Column 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      Column 3
      </div><!-- end inner row -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 five-two">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        Col 4
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
      Col 5
      </div>
    </div><!-- end inner row -->
  </div>
</div>​<!-- end outer row -->
```

Then some css

```
@media  (min-width: 768px) {
div.col-sm-7.five-three {
width: 60% !important;
}

div.col-sm-5.five-two {
width: 40% !important;
}
```

}

Here is an example: [5 equal column example](https://www.uakron.edu/it/cms/responsive-guide/gridding/five-col.dot)

And here is my full write up on coderwall

[Five equal columns in bootstrap 3](https://coderwall.com/p/wo1f-g)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion it is better to use it like this with Less syntax.
This answer is based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22799354/3356028) from @fizzix

This way columns use variables (@grid-gutter-width, media breakpoints) that user may have overriden and the behavior of five columns matches with behavior of 12 column grid.

```
/*
 * Special grid for ten columns, 
 * using its own scope 
 * so it does not interfere with the rest of the code
 */

& {
    @import (multiple) "../bootstrap-3.2.0/less/variables.less";
    @grid-columns: 5;
    @import  (multiple) "../bootstrap-3.2.0/less/mixins.less";

    @column: 1;
    .col-xs-5ths {
        .make-xs-column(@column);
    }

    .col-sm-5ths {
        .make-sm-column(@column);
    }

    .col-md-5ths {
        .make-md-column(@column);
    }

    .col-lg-5ths {
        .make-lg-column(@column);
    }
}

/***************************************/
/* Using default bootstrap now
/***************************************/

@import  (multiple) "../bootstrap-3.2.0/less/variables.less";
@import  (multiple) "../bootstrap-3.2.0/less/mixins.less";

/* ... your normal less definitions */
```

Answer (score 3):

This is awesome: http://www.ianmccullough.net/5-column-bootstrap-layout/

Just do:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-15">
```

And CSS:

```
.col-xs-15{
    width:20%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How You can add 5 columns grid in bootstrap

```css
.col-lg-1-5,.col-md-1-5,.col-sm-1-5,.col-xs-1-5{min-height:1px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;position:relative; width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;}
.item{width:100%;height:100px; background-color:#cfcfcf;}
.col-xs-1-5{width: 20%;float:left;} }

@media (min-width: 767px){ .col-sm-1-5{width: 20%;float:left;} }
@media (min-width: 992px){ .col-md-1-5{width: 20%;float:left;} }
@media (min-width: 1200px){ .col-lg-1-5{width: 20%;float:left;} }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1-5">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1-5">
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1-5">
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1-5">
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1-5">
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

By default Bootstrap does not provide grid system that allows us to create five columns layout, you need to create default column definition in the way that Bootstrap do
create some custom classes and media queries in your css file

```
.col-xs-15,
.col-sm-15,
.col-md-15,
.col-lg-15 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.col-xs-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-sm-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

and some html code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

***5 columns layout with Twitter Bootstrap style***

```
.col-xs-15 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.col-xs-15 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-xs-15 {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-xs-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-xs-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution that do not require a lot of CSS, nor tweaking bootstrap default 12col layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/0ufdyeur/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="stretch">
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { /*if not lg, change this criteria*/
  .stretch{
    width: 120%; /*the actual trick*/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new class and define its behaviour per each each media query as needed

```
@media(min-width: 768px){
  .col-1-5{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
}

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-5">col 1</div>
    <div class="col-1-5">col 2</div>
    <div class="col-1-5">col 3</div>
    <div class="col-1-5">col 4</div>
    <div class="col-1-5">col 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is a working demo https://codepen.io/giorgosk/pen/BRVorW

Answer (score 3):

**BOOTSTRAP 4**

I read all answers and I didn't find "the obvious one". Basically what you need to do is to take any bootstrap column (for example `col-2`) and edit few values. In this example I am using `.col-custom` class.

Five equal columns means each one occupies `20%`, so: `flex:0 0 20%` and `max-width:20%`. The same way you can create other number of columns (7, 9, 11, 84 or whatever you want).

You can create CSS variables with custom width, and use it in your projects. Something like that:

```
:root {
  --col-custom: 20%;
}

.col-custom {
  flex: 0 0 var(--col-custom);
  max-width: var(--col-custom);
}
```

---

**Working example:**

```css
.col-custom,
.col-sm-custom,
.col-md-custom,
.col-lg-custom,
.col-xl-custom {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-custom {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px){
  .col-sm-custom {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .col-md-custom {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .col-lg-custom {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .col-xl-custom {
    flex: 0 0 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
  }
}

/*DEMO*/
.col-custom,.col-sm-custom,.col-md-custom,.col-lg-custom,.col-xl-custom{height:100px;border:1px red solid}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-custom"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-custom"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-custom"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-custom"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-custom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In bootstrap 3, I think we can do something like that, for remove left and right margin :

```
<div class="row this_row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.this_row {
    margin: 0 -5%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the easiest solution without any need to edit CSS would be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">Column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">Column 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">Column 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <div class="col-sm-12">Column 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you need those to break beyond any breakpoint, just make btn-group block. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Five columns are clearly not the part of bootstrap by design.

But with Bootstrap v4 (alpha), there are 2 things to help with a complicated grid layout

1. Flex (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/), the new element type (official - https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)
2. Responsive utilities (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

In simple term, I'm using

```
<style>
.flexc { display: flex; align-items: center; padding: 0; justify-content: center; }
.flexc a { display: block; flex: auto; text-align: center; flex-basis: 0; }
</style>
<div class="container flexc hidden-sm-down">
  <!-- content to show in MD and larger viewport -->
  <a href="#">Link/Col 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link/Col 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link/Col 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link/Col 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link/Col 5</a>
</div>
<div class="container hidden-md-up">
  <!-- content to show in SM and smaller viewport, I don't think 5 cols in smaller viewport are gonna be alright :) -->
</div>
```

Be it 5,7,9,11,13 or something odds, it'll be okay.
I'm quite sure that 12-grids standard is able to serve more than 90% of use case - so let's design that way - develop more easier too!

The nice flex tutorial is here "https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/"

Answer (score 2):

I've created SASS mixin definitions based on bootstrap definitions for any number of columns (personally beside 12 I use 8, 10 and 24):

```
// Extended bootstrap grid system
//
// Framework grid generation
//
// Based on Bootstrap 'bootstrap/_grid-framework.scss'. Generates classes in form of `.col-(size)-x-num` of width x/num.

@mixin make-extended-grid-columns($num-columns, $i: 1, $list: ".col-xs-#{$i}-#{$num-columns}, .col-sm-#{$i}-#{$num-columns}, .col-md-#{$i}-#{$num-columns}, .col-lg-#{$i}-#{$num-columns}") {
    @for $i from (1 + 1) through $num-columns {
        $list: "#{$list}, .col-xs-#{$i}-#{$num-columns}, .col-sm-#{$i}-#{$num-columns}, .col-md-#{$i}-#{$num-columns}, .col-lg-#{$i}-#{$num-columns}";
    }
    #{$list} {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-left:  ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
        padding-right: ($grid-gutter-width / 2);
    }
}


@mixin float-extended-grid-columns($class, $num-columns, $i: 1, $list: ".col-#{$class}-#{$i}-#{$num-columns}") {
    @for $i from (1 + 1) through $num-columns {
        $list: "#{$list}, .col-#{$class}-#{$i}-#{$num-columns}";
    }
    #{$list} {
        float: left;
    }
}


@mixin calc-extended-grid-column($index, $num-columns, $class, $type) {
    @if ($type == width) and ($index > 0) {
        .col-#{$class}-#{$index}-#{$num-columns} {
            width: percentage(($index / $num-columns));
        }
    }
    @if ($type == push) and ($index > 0) {
        .col-#{$class}-push-#{$index}-#{$num-columns} {
            left: percentage(($index / $num-columns));
        }
    }
    @if ($type == pull) and ($index > 0) {
        .col-#{$class}-pull-#{$index}-#{$num-columns} {
            right: percentage(($index / $num-columns));
        }
    }
    @if ($type == offset) and ($index > 0) {
        .col-#{$class}-offset-#{$index}-#{$num-columns} {
            margin-left: percentage(($index / $num-columns));
        }
    }
}

@mixin loop-extended-grid-columns($num-columns, $class, $type) {
    @for $i from 1 through $num-columns - 1 {
        @include calc-extended-grid-column($i, $num-columns, $class, $type);
    }
}

@mixin make-extended-grid($class, $num-columns) {
    @include float-extended-grid-columns($class, $num-columns);
    @include loop-extended-grid-columns($num-columns, $class, width);
    @include loop-extended-grid-columns($num-columns, $class, pull);
    @include loop-extended-grid-columns($num-columns, $class, push);
    @include loop-extended-grid-columns($num-columns, $class, offset);
}
```

And you can simply create classes by:

```
$possible-number-extended-grid-columns: 8, 10, 24;

@each $num-columns in $possible-number-extended-grid-columns {

  // Columns

  @include make-extended-grid-columns($num-columns);

  // Extra small grid

  @include make-extended-grid(xs, $num-columns);

  // Small grid

  @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    @include make-extended-grid(sm, $num-columns);
  }

  // Medium grid

  @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
    @include make-extended-grid(md, $num-columns);
  }

  // Large grid

  @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
    @include make-extended-grid(lg, $num-columns);
  }

}
```

I hope someone will find it useful

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap or other grid system it doesn't always mean simpler and better.
Inside your .container or .row (to keep your responsive layout) u can just create 5 divs (with class .col f.e.) and add css like this:
`.col {
width: 20%;
float: left
};`

update: nowodays its better to use flexbox

Answer (score 2):

Is someone uses bootstrap-sass (v3), here is simple code for 5 columns using bootstrap mixings:

```
  .col-xs-5ths {
     @include make-xs-column(2.4);
  }

  @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
     .col-sm-5ths {
        @include make-sm-column(2.4);
     }
  }

  @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
     .col-md-5ths {
        @include make-md-column(2.4);
     }
  }

  @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
     .col-lg-5ths {
        @include make-lg-column(2.4);
     }
  }
```

Make sure you have included:

```
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
```

Comment: thanks, this was what I was looking for, i made 1-5ths 2-5ths etc and even 3-10ths etc now too, to have more flexibility, very convenient

Answer (score 1):

```css
.col-xs-2-4 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.col-sm-2-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-2-4 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
  }
}
.col-md-2-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-2-4 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
  }
}
.col-lg-2-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-2-4 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For twitter bootstrap 3 this is the most simple way to achieve this:

```
<section class="col col-sm-3" style="width: 20%;">
<section class="col col-sm-3" style="width: 20%;">
<section class="col col-sm-3" style="width: 20%;">
<section class="col col-sm-3" style="width: 20%;">
<section class="col col-sm-3" style="width: 20%;">
```

Answer (score 1):

An improvisation on @lightswitch's answer, if we need a 5 column grid using LESS iterations

```
.make-fifth-col(@index) when (@index > 0) {
  @class-name: ~".col-md-5th-@{index}";

  @{class-name} {
    .make-md-column(1.2*@index);
  }

  .make-fifth-col(@index - 1);
}

.make-fifth-col(10);
```

This will generate css classes `.col-md-5th-1, col-md-5th-2, col-md-5th-3,` and so on which corresponds to `10%`, `20%`, `30%`... respectively

Answer (score 1):

the bootstrap grid system as parted in 12 grid.So i parted it to two grid (7+5).This 7 and 5 are also contain full 12 grid.Thats why i parted 7(4+4+4) and 5(6+6) so it will take all content,simple

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 five-three">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          Column 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          Column 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          Column 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 five-two">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          Col 4
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          Col 5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.col-sm-7.five-three {
  width: 60% !important;
}
div.col-sm-5.five-two {
  width: 40% !important;
}
```

Comment: Please expand on this answer to explain the basics behind how it works.

Comment: well the bootstrap grid system as parted in 12 grid.So i parted it to two grid (7+5).This 7 and 5 are also contain full 12 grid.Thats why i parted 7(4+4+4) and 5(6+6) so it will take all content,simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the little trick to make the col-md-2 with offsets solution full width. It use the way that bootstrap does to remove(hide) 15px paddings.

I mean by adding "-" margins. Actually the calc(-10% - 15px); margins for both side. (10% is the offset width and 15px for the padding).

The only minus is it will make the page scroll horizontal so you will need the overflow-x:hidden on the parent of the row.

```
css:
.row-xs-5 {
    margin-left: calc(-10% - 15px);
    margin-right: calc(-10% - 15px);
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-sm-5 {
    margin-left: calc(-10% - 15px);
    margin-right: calc(-10% - 15px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row-md-5 {
    margin-left: calc(-10% - 15px);
    margin-right: calc(-10% - 15px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row-lg-5 {
    margin-left: calc(-10% - 15px);
    margin-right: calc(-10% - 15px);
  }
}

html:
<div style="overflow-x:hidden;">
  <div class="row row-md-5">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">col1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">col2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">col3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2">col4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-2 text-right">col5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sct3j/171/

Answer (score 1):

```
.col-half-offset{
    margin-left:4.166666667% !important;
    float: left;
}

<div className="row1 marginTop20">
    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        1
    </div>
    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-half-offset">
        2
    </div>
    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-half-offset">
        3
    </div>
    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-half-offset">
        4
    </div>
    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-half-offset">
        5
    </div>
    <div className="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred approach to this problem is to create a SASS mixin utilizing existing Bootstrap variables based on the [`make-grid-columns`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.3/scss/mixins/_grid-framework.scss#L6) mixin.

```
// Custom Grid Columns
// 
// $name - determines the class names: eg. ".col-5ths, .col-sm-5ths ..."
// $size - determines the width (2.4 is one fifth of 12, the default number of columns)
@mixin custom-grid-columns($name, $size, $grid-columns: $grid-columns, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
    $columns: round($grid-columns / $size);

    %custom-grid-column {
        @include make-col-ready();
    }

    @each $breakpoint in map-keys($breakpoints) {
        $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $breakpoints);

        .col#{$infix}-#{$name} {
            @extend %custom-grid-column;
        }

        @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
            // Create column
            .col#{$infix}-#{$name} {
                @include make-col($size);
            }

            // Create offset
            @if not ($infix=="") {
                .offset#{$infix}-#{$name} {
                    @include make-col-offset($size);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call the mixin to generate the custom column and offset classes.

```
@include custom-grid-columns('5ths', 2.4);
```

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap v4.3.1, it’s a column which is 12 / 5 = 2.4 columns wide. let’s call it col-2dot4 (and col-sm-2dot4, col-md-2dot4, …).

And each column should have 20% of the available space.

The SCSS code which comes out as below:

```
@mixin make-5-grid-column($columns: $grid-columns, $gutter: $grid-gutter-width, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {

  // Common properties for all breakpoints
  %grid-column {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: $gutter / 2;
    padding-left: $gutter / 2;
  }

  @each $breakpoint in map-keys($breakpoints) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $breakpoints);

    .col#{$infix}-2dot4 {
      @extend %grid-column;
    }

    .col#{$infix},
    .col#{$infix}-auto {
      @extend %grid-column;
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {

      // Provide basic `.col-{bp}` classes for equal-width flexbox columns
      .col#{$infix} {
        flex-basis: 0;
        flex-grow: 1;
        max-width: 100%;
      }

      .col#{$infix}-auto {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%; // Reset earlier grid tiers
      }


      .col#{$infix}-2dot4 {
        @include make-col(1, 5);
      }
    }
  }
}

@if $enable-grid-classes {
  @include make-5-grid-column();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

boostrap comes today with the possibility to fill a row evenly with built-in class that do not tell how many columns out of twelve to span :

you can use a `col`/`col-xx`  :

```css
div div div {
  border: solid;
  margin: 2px;/* this can be added without breaking the row */
}
div div div:before {
content:attr(class);/* show class used */
color:crimson
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Class used , play snippet in full page to test behavior on resizing :</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
    <div class="col-md"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

flex-grow-x could be used too

```css
div div div {
  border: solid;
  /* it allows margins too */
  margin: 3px;
}

div div div:before {
  content: attr(class);
  /* show class used */
  color: crimson
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If using bootstrap 4 and SASS (+ bootstrap variables) you can use this simplified answer:

```
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

  .col#{$infix}-fifth {
    @extend %grid-column;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints) {
    .col#{$infix}-fifth {
      flex: 0 0 20%;
      max-width: 20%;
    }
  }
}
```

Also supports breakpoints and you can simply add new `.col#{$infix}-xxx` classes

Answer (score 1):

In my case just using the `col` didn't give the right effect. All items will appear next to each other and I didn't want to figure out with PHP when to place `row` elements.

So how about creating a class to extend our bootstrap col features? In case people are wondering how to make 5 columns work with Bootstrap without using the `col` class.

mods/bootstrap.less:

```
@media @md {
    .col-md-2-4 {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 20%;
        flex: 0 0 20%;
        max-width: 20%;
    }
}
```

I named it `.col-md-2-4` because Bootstrap's 12 grid layout devided by 5 is 2.4.

Now you can create a 5 column layout. Also in combination with other breakpoint column classes:

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2-4">
   1/5 column
</div>
```

Be aware that I added a media query with less code around the statement. So if you want to add other column breakpoint classes be sure you use the right media query around it.

Comment: I named my class `.col-lg-5ths`. This is the best solution for MULTIPLES of 5, like 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc, with a 5-column layout but you have to use `@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {` in bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by adding `row-cols-5` to your row. **[Read more here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#row-columns)**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-5">
    <div class="col">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col">Col 2</div>
    <div class="col">Col 3</div>
    <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    <div class="col">Col 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
<div class="row row-cols-5">
  <div class="col border bg-primary">Col 1</div>
  <div class="col border bg-primary">Col 2</div>
  <div class="col border bg-primary">Col 3</div>
  <div class="col border bg-primary">Col 4</div>
  <div class="col border bg-primary">Col 5</div>
  <div class="col border bg-primary">Col 6</div>
  <div class="col border bg-primary">Col 7</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 5 elements with the class col-sm-2 and add to the first element also the class col-sm-offset-1

```html
<div class="equal row-fluid">
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
</div>

.equal .span2 {
    width: 17.9%;
}
```

P.s. this will not be full width (it will be indented a little from the right and left of the screen).

The code should look something like this.

Answer (score -3):

```
var cols = $(".container .item").length;
if (cols == 5){
    $('div.item').removeClass('col-md-2..etc').addClass('col-md-3').css('width', '20%');
 }
```

Jquery and Done! Framework!

Comment: It is not a good practice to rely on jquery for what we can achieve with Bootstrap.