# 5 Equal Columns on Skeleton Base Grid 1200

Tags: css, media-queries, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I would like to add the option of 5 equal columns added to my existing grid.

As far as I understand from a previous question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374652/how-do-i-divide-the-skeleton-css-boilerplate-into-5-columns) I need to add the following line to a 960 grid:

```
.container .one-fifth.column                { width: 137.6px; }
```

You can see in my sample below that my grid consists:

```
#Base 1200 Grid
#960 Grid
#Tablet (Portrait)
#Mobile (Portrait)
#Mobile (Landscape)
#Clearing */
```

What I need help with is what `{ width: ???px; }` for a 1200 grid and what width for each of the media queries after adding the line `.container .one-fifth.column`

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Thanks in advance.

Existing Grid CSS:

```
/*
* Skeleton V1.1
* Copyright 2011, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 8/17/2011
*/


/* Table of Contents
==================================================
    #Base 1200 Grid
    #960 Grid
    #Tablet (Portrait)
    #Mobile (Portrait)
    #Mobile (Landscape)
    #Clearing */



/* #Base 1200 Grid
================================================== */

    .container                                  { position: relative; width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }
    .column, .columns                           { float: left; display: inline; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }
    .row                                        { margin-bottom: 20px; }

    /* Nested Column Classes */
    .column.alpha, .columns.alpha               { margin-left: 0; }
    .column.omega, .columns.omega               { margin-right: 0; }

    /* Base Grid */
    .container .one.column                      { width: 55px;  }
    .container .two.columns                     { width: 130px; }
    .container .three.columns                   { width: 205px; }
    .container .four.columns                    { width: 280px; }
    .container .five.columns                    { width: 355px; }
    .container .six.columns                     { width: 430px; }
    .container .seven.columns                   { width: 505px; }
    .container .eight.columns                   { width: 580px; }
    .container .nine.columns                    { width: 655px; }
    .container .ten.columns                     { width: 730px; }
    .container .eleven.columns                  { width: 805px; }
    .container .twelve.columns                  { width: 880px; }
    .container .thirteen.columns                { width: 955px; }
    .container .fourteen.columns                { width: 1030px; }
    .container .fifteen.columns                 { width: 1105px; }
    .container .sixteen.columns                 { width: 1180px; }

    .container .one-third.column                { width: 380px; }
    .container .two-thirds.column               { width: 400px; }

    /* Offsets */
    .container .offset-by-one                   { padding-left: 75px;  }
    .container .offset-by-two                   { padding-left: 150px; }
    .container .offset-by-three                 { padding-left: 225px; }
    .container .offset-by-four                  { padding-left: 300px; }
    .container .offset-by-five                  { padding-left: 375px; }
    .container .offset-by-six                   { padding-left: 450px; }
    .container .offset-by-seven                 { padding-left: 525px; }
    .container .offset-by-eight                 { padding-left: 600px; }
    .container .offset-by-nine                  { padding-left: 675px; }
    .container .offset-by-ten                   { padding-left: 750px; }
    .container .offset-by-eleven                { padding-left: 825px; }
    .container .offset-by-twelve                { padding-left: 900px; }
    .container .offset-by-thirteen              { padding-left: 975px; }
    .container .offset-by-fourteen              { padding-left: 1050px; }
    .container .offset-by-fifteen               { padding-left: 1125px; }



/* #960 Grid
================================================== */

    /* Note: Design for a width of 960px */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
        .container                                  {
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
        .column, .columns                           { float: left; display: inline; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }
        .row                                        { margin-bottom: 20px; }

        /* Nested Column Classes */
        .column.alpha, .columns.alpha               { margin-left: 0; }
        .column.omega, .columns.omega               { margin-right: 0; }

        /* Base Grid */
        .container .one.column                      { width: 40px;  }
        .container .two.columns                     { width: 100px; }
        .container .three.columns                   { width: 160px; }
        .container .four.columns                    { width: 220px; }
        .container .five.columns                    { width: 280px; }
        .container .six.columns                     { width: 340px; }
        .container .seven.columns                   { width: 400px; }
        .container .eight.columns                   { width: 460px; }
        .container .nine.columns                    { width: 520px; }
        .container .ten.columns                     { width: 580px; }
        .container .eleven.columns                  { width: 640px; }
        .container .twelve.columns                  { width: 700px; }
        .container .thirteen.columns                { width: 760px; }
        .container .fourteen.columns                { width: 820px; }
        .container .fifteen.columns                 { width: 880px; }
        .container .sixteen.columns                 { width: 940px; }

        .container .one-third.column                { width: 300px; }
        .container .two-thirds.column               { width: 620px; }

        /* Offsets */
        .container .offset-by-one                   { padding-left: 60px;  }
        .container .offset-by-two                   { padding-left: 120px; }
        .container .offset-by-three                 { padding-left: 180px; }
        .container .offset-by-four                  { padding-left: 240px; }
        .container .offset-by-five                  { padding-left: 300px; }
        .container .offset-by-six                   { padding-left: 360px; }
        .container .offset-by-seven                 { padding-left: 420px; }
        .container .offset-by-eight                 { padding-left: 480px; }
        .container .offset-by-nine                  { padding-left: 540px; }
        .container .offset-by-ten                   { padding-left: 600px; }
        .container .offset-by-eleven                { padding-left: 660px; }
        .container .offset-by-twelve                { padding-left: 720px; }
        .container .offset-by-thirteen              { padding-left: 780px; }
        .container .offset-by-fourteen              { padding-left: 840px; }
        .container .offset-by-fifteen               { padding-left: 900px; }
    }


/* #Tablet (Portrait)
================================================== */

    /* Note: Design for a width of 768px */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
        .container                                  { width: 768px; }
        .container .column,
        .container .columns                         { margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;  }
        .column.alpha, .columns.alpha               { margin-left: 0; margin-right: 10px; }
        .column.omega, .columns.omega               { margin-right: 0; margin-left: 10px; }

        .container .one.column                      { width: 28px; }
        .container .two.columns                     { width: 76px; }
        .container .three.columns                   { width: 124px; }
        .container .four.columns                    { width: 172px; }
        .container .five.columns                    { width: 220px; }
        .container .six.columns                     { width: 268px; }
        .container .seven.columns                   { width: 316px; }
        .container .eight.columns                   { width: 364px; }
        .container .nine.columns                    { width: 412px; }
        .container .ten.columns                     { width: 460px; }
        .container .eleven.columns                  { width: 508px; }
        .container .twelve.columns                  { width: 556px; }
        .container .thirteen.columns                { width: 604px; }
        .container .fourteen.columns                { width: 652px; }
        .container .fifteen.columns                 { width: 700px; }
        .container .sixteen.columns                 { width: 748px; }

        .container .one-third.column                { width: 236px; }
        .container .two-thirds.column               { width: 492px; }

        /* Offsets */
        .container .offset-by-one                   { padding-left: 48px; }
        .container .offset-by-two                   { padding-left: 96px; }
        .container .offset-by-three                 { padding-left: 144px; }
        .container .offset-by-four                  { padding-left: 192px; }
        .container .offset-by-five                  { padding-left: 240px; }
        .container .offset-by-six                   { padding-left: 288px; }
        .container .offset-by-seven                 { padding-left: 336px; }
        .container .offset-by-eight                 { padding-left: 348px; }
        .container .offset-by-nine                  { padding-left: 432px; }
        .container .offset-by-ten                   { padding-left: 480px; }
        .container .offset-by-eleven                { padding-left: 528px; }
        .container .offset-by-twelve                { padding-left: 576px; }
        .container .offset-by-thirteen              { padding-left: 624px; }
        .container .offset-by-fourteen              { padding-left: 672px; }
        .container .offset-by-fifteen               { padding-left: 720px; }
    }


/*  #Mobile (Portrait)
================================================== */

    /* Note: Design for a width of 320px */

    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .container { width: 300px; }
        .columns, .column { margin: 0; }

        .container .one.column,
        .container .two.columns,
        .container .three.columns,
        .container .four.columns,
        .container .five.columns,
        .container .six.columns,
        .container .seven.columns,
        .container .eight.columns,
        .container .nine.columns,
        .container .ten.columns,
        .container .eleven.columns,
        .container .twelve.columns,
        .container .thirteen.columns,
        .container .fourteen.columns,
        .container .fifteen.columns,
        .container .sixteen.columns,
        .container .one-third.column,
        .container .two-thirds.column  { width: 300px; }

        /* Offsets */
        .container .offset-by-one,
        .container .offset-by-two,
        .container .offset-by-three,
        .container .offset-by-four,
        .container .offset-by-five,
        .container .offset-by-six,
        .container .offset-by-seven,
        .container .offset-by-eight,
        .container .offset-by-nine,
        .container .offset-by-ten,
        .container .offset-by-eleven,
        .container .offset-by-twelve,
        .container .offset-by-thirteen,
        .container .offset-by-fourteen,
        .container .offset-by-fifteen { padding-left: 0; }

    }


/* #Mobile (Landscape)
================================================== */

    /* Note: Design for a width of 480px */

    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        .container { width: 420px; }
        .columns, .column { margin: 0; }

        .container .one.column,
        .container .two.columns,
        .container .three.columns,
        .container .four.columns,
        .container .five.columns,
        .container .six.columns,
        .container .seven.columns,
        .container .eight.columns,
        .container .nine.columns,
        .container .ten.columns,
        .container .eleven.columns,
        .container .twelve.columns,
        .container .thirteen.columns,
        .container .fourteen.columns,
        .container .fifteen.columns,
        .container .sixteen.columns,
        .container .one-third.column,
        .container .two-thirds.column { width: 420px; }
    }


/* #Clearing
================================================== */

    /* Self Clearing Goodness */
    .container:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }

    /* Use clearfix class on parent to clear nested columns,
    or wrap each row of columns in a <div class="row"> */
    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after,
    .row:before,
    .row:after {
      content: '\0020';
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 0;
      height: 0; }
    .row:after,
    .clearfix:after {
      clear: both; }
    .row,
    .clearfix {
      zoom: 1; }

    /* You can also use a <br class="clear" /> to clear columns */
    .clear {
      clear: both;
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For 1200 grid

`.container .one-fifth.column                { width: 220px; } 
.container .two-fifths.column               { width: 420px; } 
.container .three-fifths.column             { width: 640px; }
.container .four-fifths.column              { width: 760px; }`

For 960 grid

`.container .one-fifth.column                { width: 172px; }
.container .two-fifths.column               { width: 364px; }
.container .three-fifths.column             { width: 556px; }
.container .four-fifths.column              { width: 748px; }`

Tablet (Portrait)

`.container .one-fifth.column                { width: 133.6px; }
.container .two-fifths.column               { width: 287.2px; }
.container .three-fifths.column             { width: 440.8px; }
.container .four-fifths.column              { width: 594.4px; }`

Mobile (Portrait)

`.container .one-fifth.column,
.container .two-fifths.column,
.container .three-fifths.column,
.container .four-fifths.column              { width: 300px; }`