# 5 Equal Spans in 1 Row - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the fluid grid layout I can get 4 equal spans:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span3">...</div>
  <div class="span3">...</div>
  <div class="span3">...</div>
  <div class="span3">...</div>
</div>
```

Or I can get 6 equal spans:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span2">...</div>
  <div class="span2">...</div>
  <div class="span2">...</div>
  <div class="span2">...</div>
  <div class="span2">...</div>
  <div class="span2">...</div>
</div>
```

But how do I get 5 equal spans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that by default bootstrap is 12 columns, you cannot mathematically get 5 equal spans.

However, if you really need to (bad idea, more on that in a second), you can customize your bootstrap download to have 15 columns.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

Change the `@gridColumns` variable to 15, then use 5 columns all with a `span3`.

It is a bad idea though. Bootstrap is 12 columns because 12 works well. Using 12 gives you support for 1/4, 1/3, and 1/2 width columns. With a 15 column layout, you will only have support for 1/3rd width (and a lot of strange other sizes). Your call though, the setting is there.

Comment: yes, it's a bad idea. i've found a different answer which is working and have the default 12 columns bootstrap. read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14496611/1057527) and after that, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16526908/1057527)

Comment: “It is a bad idea though.” Not if your design works with 5 columns.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The great thing about 12 is you can stack half, one-third, one-fourth, and one-sixth width columns. With 15 columns, you can only have one-third and one-fifth width columns. You have less options when trying to build equal width layouts.

Comment: @MikeRobinson: yup, I know. Still not a bad idea if the design works.

Answer (score 14):

I have followed bootstraps methods for calculating widths and have come up with the following. You will want to follow the HTML structure of as follows:

```
<div class="row-fluid-5">
    <div class="span2">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="span2">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="span2">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="span2">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="span2">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Then, after you load bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css, load your custom.css file with the following:

```
/* CUSTOM 5 COLUMN SPAN LAYOUT
  *
  * based on http://gridcalculator.dk/
  * width => 1200, gutter => 15px, margin => 15px, columns => 5
  */
 .row-fluid-5 {
   width: 100%;
   *zoom: 1;
 }
 .row-fluid-5:before,
 .row-fluid-5:after {
   display: table;
   line-height: 0;
   content: "";
 }
 .row-fluid-5:after {
   clear: both;
 }
 .row-fluid-5 [class*="span"] {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 30px;
   margin-left: 1.875%;
   *margin-left: 1.875%;

   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
           box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .row-fluid-5 .controls-row [class*="span"] + [class*="span"] {

   margin-left: 1.875%;
 }
 .row-fluid-5 [class*="span"]:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
 }
 .row-fluid-5 .span2 {
   width: 18.5%;
   *width: 18.5%;
 }

 /* responsive ONLY */

 @media (max-width: 600px){ /* spans reduce to 100px then go full width */

    .row-fluid-5 [class*="span"]{
    margin-left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px; 
    }
 }
```

Check out the demo below to see how it works.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S5ps6/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to [generate](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) custom grid (e.g. 10). There is no way to create 5 equal raws in 12 column grid

Answer (score 1):

Or you could add this to your css (or the bootstrap.css) - This is my preferred way to solve this.  The "15" used to throw me a little bit, but just try to remind yourself it's 1/5th.

```
.col-xs-15,
.col-sm-15,
.col-md-15,
.col-lg-15 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.col-xs-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-sm-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Then just use it like you would any other bootstrap class.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is mathematic. Not a real CSS/Bootstrap problem...

You'll not be able to create 5 equal spans within a row because the default grid columns of Bootstrap is 12, and `12 / 5 = 2.4`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have converted this into a 10/2 = 5 problem by creating a fluid row of span10 and then having child fluid rows with span2 children. The following works:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid span10">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2">...</div>
                <div class="span2">...</div>
                <div class="span2">...</div>
                <div class="span2">...</div>
                <div class="span2">...</div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid span10">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2">...</div>
                <div class="span2">...</div>
                <div class="span2">...</div>
                <div class="span2">...</div>
                <div class="span2">...</div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: The parent element won't span the full width of the document though?

Comment: mathematically it cannot but, the children wrap up neatly.

Answer (score 0):

```
.span3 {   width: 220px; }
.span2 {   width: 140px; }
```

or

```
.row-fluid .span3 {   width: 23.404255319148934%;   *width:
23.351063829787233%; }

.row-fluid .span2 {   width: 14.893617021276595%;   *width:
14.840425531914894%; }
```

Those are only provided width of element, you should be able to simply add

```
class="span" style="width:180px"
```

or

```
class="span" style="width:19.1488%"
```

You need to add class span cos bootstrap need those for `.row` works.