# 5 columns in bootstrap impossible?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Client has 5 pricing options. I'm using wells to display the price points. since Bootstrap uses columns instead of percentages, is it not possible to create even columns out of the box?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ulaMiZoz/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## For Boostrap 3

I posted a solution to this that works far better than the selected answer for Bootstrap 3.

Works seamlessly with Bootstrap 3 classes and is completely responsive. it does not leave blank spaces like other solutions. It creates 5 equal columns.

**[HERE IS THE CORRECT ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22799354/1799136)**

Answer (score 2):

Yeah its possible.  There is a total of `12` columns to span So if you make each column span `2` and leave `1` column empty on the left and right.  Then you can evenly do five columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">5</div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/95652

Comment: I'll consider this the answer, since the question was "is it possible". You can see the downside of this is the extra spacing that may not match the rest of the design, but again, not included in original question. Visual example: http://www.bootply.com/95654