# Grid system in Bootstrap3 for five columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a bootstrap template and facing a problem with grid system. In my template it has five columns in a row. Each column must be equal. It will not be a problem if it is three, four or six columns. I can write it easily by `col-md-3` or `col-md-4` or `col-md-6` . But how can i right that for five columns. Is there any way or need to write custom css? Please tell me.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Would you be willing to create a complementary stylesheet with LESS ?

Answer (score 0):

Write your own selector col-md-5 and just copy properties from that selectors and set width: to a 20%. That should works :)

Comment: `col-md-5` in a 12-columns grid has a width of 5/12 not 20%
The name should be entirely different

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is quite simple if you are using bootstrap 4. just do like this and there will be equal 5 columns.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>Bootstrap 4 Five Columns</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h3>column 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h3>column 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h3>column 3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h3>column 4</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h3>column 5</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also sharing reference link below for further understanding.
[Equal Columns](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp)