# Bootstrap custom grid-columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How i can make custom grid-columns just for one element of `div` ?
I need to 5 column per row (20% width for each one).

Example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">...</div> <!-- 1 -->
        <div class="col-md-2">...</div> <!-- 2 -->
        <div class="col-md-2">...</div> <!-- 3 -->
        <div class="col-md-2">...</div> <!-- 4 -->
        <div class="col-md-2">...</div> <!-- 5 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1

Comment: This is a recurring question, multiple answers are already given here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: @Seb33300 Thanks, I found this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14496611/1012405

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial solution would be the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13998370/1419575) (adding an offset).

However if you want to do it right, you'll have to create new classes to override Bootstrap's defaults with the appropriate width. Then add this class to each column.

```
.5-col-grid {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Additionally you can set CSS @media support if you want 100% width at smaller screen resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

I built out a solution to this using LESS that doesn't require modification of Bootstrap. https://github.com/drew-r/bootstrap-n-column

Comment: Looks like a cool solution, it would be annoying to build a new custom package every time I want to update bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You actually dont have to, in the updated Bootstrap. You can download a custom Bootstrap 3 build, specifying the number of desired columns with the @grid-columns setting.

Go to url

```
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
```

scroll down to "Grid system" and enter your own values for the custom grid system you desire.

Comment: The person asking the question said "just for one element", so not for his/her whole site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own set of rule, taking Boostrap's way of structuring its grid as reference:

```
.col-custom-five {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Usually five columns don't work well on really small device. So what I usually do is add a common `xs` declaration along with it. Something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-custom-five col-xs-6">...</div> <!-- 1 -->
    <div class="col-custom-five col-xs-6">...</div> <!-- 2 -->
    <div class="col-custom-five col-xs-6">...</div> <!-- 3 -->
    <div class="col-custom-five col-xs-6">...</div> <!-- 4 -->
    <div class="col-custom-five col-xs-6">...</div> <!-- 5 -->
</div>
```

EDIT:

You can also generate all the custom rules directly from Bootstrap's website as well: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system

Comment: Thanks but I is not responsive.

Comment: It is. It all depends on what you want to do inside each div too, and how you want it to act at different breakpoints. It's all open for customization

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own column then you need to give the div a class and then style it.

You need to specify the custom width and then make sure you float it to the left and add padding.

**For example:**

```css
.custom-col {

  width:20%;
  float:left;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;

}
```

```html
<div class="custom-columns>
  <div class="container>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="custom-col">
        <p>Sample text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-col">
      <p>Sample text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-col">
      <p>Sample text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-col">
      <p>Sample text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-col">
      <p>Sample text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Default bootstrap grid system comes with 12 columns.

If you want to define a custom one, you need to customize however you want [on this page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)