# Dynamic HTML Table's td and tr not working properly depending on the condition

Tags: php, html, html-table

I' am storing the values in an array and then looping through it and creating dynamic HTML td and tr depedning on the condition. The table tr should break to next tr when the loop increament value is 6 and 11.

I' am not sure what I' am I missing here. Everything does look okay. Here is the [screenshots](http://s9.postimg.org/g38hs7u33/table.jpg)

**PHP CODE**

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="tblareaXP">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="5">Areas of Expertise</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
        $i = 0;
        $array = array(
          "Program Management" => "Program Management",
          "Finance Administration" => "Finance Administration",
          "Training  Facilitation" => "Training  Facilitation",
          "Operations  Logistics" => "Operations  Logistics",
          "Communications  Media" => "Communications  Media",
          "Monitoring  Evaluation" => "Monitoring  Evaluation",
          "Board Goveranance" => "Board Goveranance",
          "Research  Learning" => "Research  Learning",
          "Strategic Planning" => "Strategic Planning",
          "Program Design" => "Program Design",
          "Other Area" => "Other Area"
        );
        foreach( $array as $key => $item ){
            $i++;
      ?>
            <?php if( $i == 6 or $i == 11 ){ ?><tr><?php } ?>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><label for="">&nbsp;<?php echo $item; ?></label></td>
      <?php if( $i == 6 or $i == 11 ){ ?></tr><?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You realize only your 6th and 11th <td> elements will have a <tr> enclosing them, which is not same as breaking to next <tr> ? If you understand this, try thinking of a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code generates HTML that looks like this:

```
<tbody>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Program Management"><label for="">&nbsp;Program Management</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Finance Administration"><label for="">&nbsp;Finance Administration</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Training  Facilitation"><label for="">&nbsp;Training  Facilitation</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Operations  Logistics"><label for="">&nbsp;Operations  Logistics</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Communications  Media"><label for="">&nbsp;Communications  Media</label></td>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Monitoring  Evaluation"><label for="">&nbsp;Monitoring  Evaluation</label></td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Board Goveranance"><label for="">&nbsp;Board Goveranance</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Research  Learning"><label for="">&nbsp;Research  Learning</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Strategic Planning"><label for="">&nbsp;Strategic Planning</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Program Design"><label for="">&nbsp;Program Design</label></td>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Other Area"><label for="">&nbsp;Other Area</label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

See how the lines wrapped in `<tr>` end up on their own line? What you really want to be generating is something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Program Management"><label for="">&nbsp;Program Management</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Finance Administration"><label for="">&nbsp;Finance Administration</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Training  Facilitation"><label for="">&nbsp;Training  Facilitation</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Operations  Logistics"><label for="">&nbsp;Operations  Logistics</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Communications  Media"><label for="">&nbsp;Communications  Media</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Monitoring  Evaluation"><label for="">&nbsp;Monitoring  Evaluation</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Board Goveranance"><label for="">&nbsp;Board Goveranance</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Research  Learning"><label for="">&nbsp;Research  Learning</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Strategic Planning"><label for="">&nbsp;Strategic Planning</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Program Design"><label for="">&nbsp;Program Design</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="Other Area"><label for="">&nbsp;Other Area</label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then each row is wrapped in a `<tr>`. How do you do this, then? Well, first try putting all items in one row:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach($array as $key => $item): ?>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><label for="">&nbsp;<?php echo $item; ?></label></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And that’s a good start! All you need to do now is have it end the last row and start a new row every 5 columns.  Fortunately, that’s easy enough:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach($array as $key => $item) {
            if($i > 0 && $i % 5 === 0) {
                echo '</tr><tr>';
            }
            $i++;
    ?>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><label for="">&nbsp;<?php echo $item; ?></label></td>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Presto! But still, I have to call you out for your use of tables. That’s not tabular data. That’s layout. Impostor! So let’s try to figure out how to do this a different way. It looks like you’re using Bootstrap. *I wonder if it has anything to help with this… aha!*

## Enter [the grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Skimming briefly through [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), you should be able to set up a grid pretty easily. First, rather than a `table`/`tbody`, wrap the whole thing in a `container-fluid`. Then, rather than `td`s, wrap each item in a `col-md-2` or something. (Actually, it appears that there’s no provision for five columns in Bootstrap, but there’s [another question on Stack Overflow for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap).) Result:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<?php foreach($array as $key => $item): ?>
    <div class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" name="prodevxp" value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><label for="">&nbsp;<?php echo $item; ?></label></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

This solution

- is more semantically correct
- does not require us to keep an extra index variable
- is responsive to small screen sizes (I think)
- *is better*

Comment: Thank you very much for the great explanation. I have learnt something new today.