# Divide a row in 5 columns in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

How do you equally divide a row in 5 columns in Bootstrap 4 where it has 12 columns total? Anyone knows?

Comment: 12/5 needs fraction?

Comment: can you show diagrameticaly your expected output

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this - it's a perfectly valid question, especially for people coming from version 3.

Comment: why people down vote it? because stackoverflow is run by a bunch of scrum masters who have 0 answers but like to downvote stuff because 'it doesn't fit the page'. This question is a perfect example.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't use floats like version 3 did so it can automatically space out your columns using just the `col` class. So for 5 equally spaced columns, just do this:

```css
.col1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.col2 {
  background-color: green;
}
.col3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.col4 {
  background-color: orange;
}
.col5 {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col1">Column 1</div>
    <div class="col col2">Column 2</div>
    <div class="col col3">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col col4">Column 4</div>
    <div class="col col5">Column 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the answer is slightly incomplete because it doesn't mention for example `col-md-auto` e.g. you can combine `col-12` and `col-md-auto`

Comment: This answer wont help if you've got a row with < 5 items but still want a 5-col grid. Instead it'll stretch the items to fill the grid.

Comment: @DavidG that works great, but can you suggest how to expand it (to `col-sm-12`) in responsive view.

Comment: @Sk446 can't you just add an empty col?

Comment: `col-12` with `col-md` also works for equally spaced columns that fill the full width of the row on md+ res

Comment: not really usefull when you want 2 rows with 5 columns in a div.row

Comment: There is a new improved answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66546867/9207553