# How can adjust the Bootstrap column classes so all the span tags doesn’t exceed 12?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<HeaderTemplate>
   <span class="col-xs-3">ID</span>
   <span class="col-xs-3">Product</span>
   <span class="col-xs-3"> Unit Price</span>
   <span class="col-xs-3">On Hand</span>
   <span class="col-xs-3">Total</span> 
</HeaderTemplate>
```

How can I adjust the Bootstrap column classes so the total for  all the span tags doesn’t exceed 12 with this example above?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little bit? make an image or something, so that others can understand your question!

Comment: @Afshin Is that better?

Comment: @Afshin Basicially I don't want any span element to go to the next line because I believe there is a rule for that in bootstrap.

Comment: Bootstrap is there to make it responsive when the resolution changes. For example, in bigger screens you will see 12 cols, in a bit smaller ones 6 cols, and in the smallest ones just one column. If you want to override this rule and have exactly 12 columns per row, then you wont need bootstrap!

Comment: @Afshin I tried changing this statement "col-xs-3" to this "col-xs-2" all inside of span elements but that didn't work either. I am lost. Do you want to see the whole application or is what I posted sufficient enough?

Comment: @Afshin Are you still there?

Comment: @Afshin Never mind. I changed them all to "col-xs-2" with the exception of third and fourth span (col-xs-2 text-right)- in this headertemplate and itemtemplate and it worked!

Comment: That's is one of the problem with Bootstrap as 5 columns cannot be distribute equally among 12. You can refer to this link for the fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944691/bootstrap-5-column-layout

Answer (score 1):

```
                        <span class="col-xs-2">ID</span>
                        <span class="col-xs-2">Product</span>
                        <span class="col-xs-2"> Unit Price</span>
                        <span class="col-xs-2">On Hand</span>
                        <span class="col-xs-4">Total</span>
```

The sum of columns should not exceed 12 so you can to something like this to make it 12.