# How to create a 5 equal columns in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a selection link that has 10 containers. And what I want is to divide them into 5 equal columns. Now my problem is I want to expand the width of the columns. Means I dont have a `container` class in my parent row.

Here's my sample code:

```
<div id="categories-selections">
    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
        <img src="public/images/cat1.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
        <img src="public/images/cat2.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
        <img src="public/images/cat3.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
        <img src="public/images/cat4.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
        <img src="public/images/cat5.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
        <img src="public/images/cat6.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
        <img src="public/images/cat7.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
        <img src="public/images/cat8.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
        <img src="public/images/cat9.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 no-padding">
        <img src="public/images/cat10.png" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Here's what should be the output:
[image]

And here's what I have:

[image]

That's all guys I hope you can help me.

Here's the sample fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mk7bdyey/

Comment: can you please share live link or demo? that will be ease and also please describe little bit more. You want to have like first image and you have structure like second image?

Comment: You should use `.container-fluid` for full width sections. This question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap covers 20% width columns.

Comment: Yes in my current setup I came up with the output of the second image.

Comment: you can add <div class=container-fluid"></div> as a parent row so it takes full width

Comment: Still same effect when I add container-fluid as a parent div.

Comment: Wait ill try to make a live demo

Comment: Here's the sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mk7bdyey/

Comment: You're using `.col-md-offset` which is creating space on both sides instead of having 5 actual equal width columns. As I said, follow the directions on this question to add classes for 1/5 columns - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am checking it now.

Comment: Specifically, the 'For Bootstrap 3 and above' answer will solve your problem. The top answer is not correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just create a whole new column all together

```
.col-xs-15,
.col-sm-15,
.col-md-15,
.col-lg-15 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Next you need to define width of new classes in case of different media queries.

```
.col-xs-15 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-sm-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-15 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

then you can just use like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the padding from left and right as per your requirement to the `div` in which you have given `id="categories-selections"`. you can put in-line css like `style="padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px;"`

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try. I also included the fiddle in my question.