# How can I get auto-width columns in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How do I get auto-width-columns in Bootstrap like in UIKit?

I need 5 columns with auto width.

In UIKit you get it with `<div class="uk-width-1-5">`

Comment: Foundation has this feature.

Comment: not really clear what is asked: auto-width on content, or equal column auto-width on available space

Answer (score 26):

Bootstrap 4+ you can use the col class alone and it will resize to what space is available.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Josh. How can I implement that with bootstrap 3.3.7?

Comment: You can't. Auto width calculation is a feature only available with `flexbox`

Comment: @AllanJebaraj although flexbox is only present at Bootstrap 4+, it doesn't mean you can't. You can study flexbox and apply your own CSS rules to override the columns styles and apply the auto-width. =]

Comment: It's been a year and a half ! :P Thank you @giovannipds I didn't have control over the library as many components and layouts have been defined in that version and I didn't want to complicate the already complicated codebase ;)

Comment: @AllanJebaraj haha, no worries! If you need it anytime, just say it, it's simples to implement a little css class extension for that. =]

Answer (score 24):

Using `class="col"` will automatically make the columns equal in size.

But if you want some column(s) to resize depending on its/there content(s), use something like `class="col-auto"`.

> Use `class="col-{breakpoint}-auto"` classes to size columns based on
>   the **natural width of their content**.
>
> Reference:
>   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#variable-width-content

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2023)**

Bootstrap 5 still uses a flexbox grid so [auto-sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/layout/#auto-sizing) is still possible using the `.col` to `.col-auto` classes so that columns take up as much space as needed.

**Bootstrap 4**

Bootstrap 4 uses a flexbox grid so auto-width columns are achieved using the `col` and/or `col-auto` classes. The `col` class will create equal width columns, while `col-auto` columns will shrink to fit the width of their content.

**Bootstrap 3 (original answer)**

The 5 columns aspect of this question has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap). Since Bootstrap has 12 columns, you only use 10 of them with 5 col-*-2 units

http://codeply.com/go/QXiPmtgJUJ

In terms of "auto-width", Bootstrap 4 will have new auto-layout columns that consume the remaining portion of any row, but this is still based on a 12 column grid.