# Five (20%) equal divs with 20px margin-right on one row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I get 5 (20% equal) floating divs on one row with 20px margin-right between in each except the last-child?

Structure:

```
<div class="f-item pull-left">1</div>
<div class="f-item pull-left">2</div>
<div class="f-item pull-left">3</div>
<div class="f-item pull-left">4</div>
<div class="f-item pull-left">5</div>
```

Tried with the following, which breaks the row (and "reset" on last-child seems to be ignored):

```
.f-item {
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 20%;

    &:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jc2gvddg/) with example.

```css
.f-group {
  width: 100%;
}

.f-item {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.f-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.col-sm-12 {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="f-group">
    <div class="f-item pull-left">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="f-item pull-left">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="f-item pull-left">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="f-item pull-left">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="f-item pull-left">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
```

Comment: Take a look at calc() and/or flexbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Five equal columns in twitter bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: It's funny, if you have five 20% divs on one row then there can't be margins or else it would not be 20% right?  lol I know what you mean though but i thought this is funny. You could have 5 divs of 20% and have padding on the inside or you can use flex, many ways to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the item width to allow for the margin width...

```
.f-item {
    width: calc(20% - 16px);
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;

    &:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7e1pdttt/1/

CSS only:

```
.f-item {
    width: calc(20% - 16px);
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
.f-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
 }
```

http://www.bootply.com/jxKTTBZsSi

Comment: cheers, was testing calc() as you commented and ran into the same "issue" I see in your fiddle. How to take account for removing margin-right on the last item and still have equal divs?

Comment: Its in the math. Updated my answer. Add 4 more pixels on each item to adjust for the missing margin-right on the last child (4*4=16). Also took away `clearfix` so that the last-child selector works.

Comment: For starting users, it might be useful to include the compiled CSS.

Comment: Updated my answer with CSS

Answer (score 1):

Consider [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.f-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.f-item {
  margin-right: 20px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #eee;
}

.f-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="f-items">
  <div class="f-item pull-left">1</div>
  <div class="f-item pull-left">2</div>
  <div class="f-item pull-left">3</div>
  <div class="f-item pull-left">4</div>
  <div class="f-item pull-left">5</div>
</div>
```