# Bootstrap CSS noob - skeleton code for 5x5 grid with nested grid in each "cell"

Tags: html, css, grid, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a seating chart app that looks something like this:
[image: layout]

I'm not sure if it can be done with all Bootstrap, because I read that BS "container" class cannot be nested. Also, I'd really like it if I could make the entire chart automatically stretch to both the full width and height of the viewport. I'm currently doing it with a 5x5 html table with a BS grid in each td. I'm currently having problems getting the "gutter" spacing to look right (red bars in diagram). I'm also having trouble getting all of the elements to fit inside the "row" (BS "row" class).

[image]

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3"><input id="39638" type="text" value=""></div><div class="col-xs-3"><label id="39638pc"><?php echo $part['39638'] ?></label></div>
            <div class="col-xs-3"><input id="39638bt" type="text" value=""></div><div class="col-xs-3"><label id="39638bc"><?php echo $part['39638'] ?></div></label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12"><label class="name-label">Opas</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="participate(39638)">Good</button></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="behave(39638)">Bad</button></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="comelate(39638)">Late</button></div>
        </div></td>
```

In style.css:

```
    table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    /* padding: 8px; */
}

.row .col-xs-3 {
    display: inline-block; 
    float: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.row .col-xs-4 {
    display: inline-block; 
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.row .col-xs-3 input, .row .col-xs-3 label {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: pink;
}

.row .col-xs-4 button {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

td .row {
    margin: 0px;
}

.name-label {
    width: 100%;
    font: bold 14px calibri, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's what you want, but what is the question???? Having trouble isn't a question

Comment: How to solve the trouble?

Comment: In other words, what would the skeleton code be for this grid? or... Why isn't my code working?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with all BS. You don't need to nest more than one container; you can just nest the rows and columns.

A 5x5 grid is a little tricky, since 12 is not evenly divisible by 5, but there is a beautiful solution to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap).

Here is the [HTML code](https://pastebin.com/rUg4J2tz).

Here is the [CSS](https://pastebin.com/1QjhPZ1j).

Here's what it looks like:[image]

The keys to making it work were using the BS "text-center" class and using `display: table-row;` and `display: table-cell;` in the css.

Now if I could only get the elements centered vertically...