# Create a grid of 10 columns with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to create a 10-column layout with Bootstrap?  `col-md-1` gives 12 and `col-md-2` gives 6, but I need 10. How can I achieve that? Are there any CSS "hacks" for this?

I was thinking about pasting two 5-column grids next to each other (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap) question/answer), but I'm not sure how to approach that.

Comment: @ehsan Because bootstrap always needs to add up to 12. So 12 times col-md-1 gives a column of 12, while 12 of col-md-2 gives 2 columns of six.

Comment: what you need??

Comment: maybe just inside your 12 column grid you can create a special class like you said col-md-2-5, and set width to 10%

Comment: @ehsan I need a 10 column layout with bootrstap (centered, and responsive).

Comment: @twan , you want change 12 columns to 10 columns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Bootstrap 3:**

If you want it with on full width, you can use [this approach](https://blog.polarbits.co/2014/02/16/quick-tips-5-column-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap/).

But instead of 20% (1/5 *100%), you have to use: 10%:

```css
.col-xs-1-10,
.col-sm-1-10 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}

.col-xs-1-10 {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-1-10 {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-1-10 {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-1-10 {
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1-10">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1-10">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1-10">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1-10">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1-10">
    5
  </div>
   <div class="col-xs-1-10">
    6
  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1-10">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1-10">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1-10">
    9
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1-10">
    10
  </div>
</div>
```

**Bootstrap 4:**

Use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22799354/5418124).

Comment: The first link is broken: *"Server error. 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."*

Answer (score 2):

Just like the question/answer you linked, create 10 columns (instead of 5), with the first column having an offset like this:

```css
div[class^="col-xs-1"] {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">7</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">9</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">10</div>
</div>
```

Hope this is what you are aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we can customize the length of columns in the grid system using the source code of Bootstrap and Sass. [Read here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid)

First, create a [SCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) file named *myBootstrap.scss* and type in:

```
$grid-columns: 10;
```

Next, [download](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/#source-files) the source code of Bootstrap and [import](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/#importing) it in the SCSS file:

```
@import "bootstrap-4.3.1/scss/bootstrap" // bootstrap.scss is the file you need to import.
```

Then, we have this in *myBootstrap.scss*:

```
$grid-columns: 10;

@import "bootstrap-4.3.1/scss/bootstrap";
```

Finally, install [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) and compile it into *myBootstrap.css* on the command line or you can do it in your way:

```
sass myBootstrap.scss myBootstrap.css
```

Now, just replace your original CSS content of Bootstrap with *myBootstrap.css*:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myBootstrap.css">
```

Done.  You can read more in [Theming Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/).