# Non 12-divisible Equal columns on Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a little web app that I want to show 5 columns responsive equal width.

But I only want this layout for a devices with ≥992px of width.
For devices <992px of width I want to show the 5 HTML elements in one full-width row.

> Equal-width columns can be broken into multiple lines, but there was a
>   [Safari flexbox bug](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#11-min-and-max-size-declarations-are-ignored-when-wrapping-flex-items) that prevented this from working without an
>   explicit `flex-basis` or `border`.
>
> Two workarounds have been documented in a [reduced test case outside
>   Bootstrap](https://output.jsbin.com/micohor), though if the browser is up to date this shouldn’t be
>   necessary.

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

So, I'm a bit confused in how can I achieve this responsive behaviour that I want using Bootstrap 4.

I have this "idea", but I think will pretty ugly, what do you think about it?

Let's consider this markup

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="sep"></div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="sep"></div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="sep"></div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, with jQuery I can select `.sep` and add bootstrap4 class `w-100` in the case of width <992px.

Thanks for reading and please forgive my bad english.

Comment: Have you considered using [CSS Grid layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)? If you've dismissed them as inappropriate it would be worth updating your question, using the [edit] link, in order to prevent answers that suggest its use.

Comment: I don't know about CSS Grid layouts, I will check it up, please feel free to post an answer using that approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand the question. Why not just use the `lg` auto layout columns (`col-lg`)?

https://www.codeply.com/go/OohsSfM7Zu

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to remember about Bootstrap is that rows **must** contain `12` columns. If you have a row with a number that doesn't go into `12` (such as `5`), you should be making use of **offsets**.

For example, `12 / 5` is `2`, with `2` left over. So you want to make use of columns that occupy a width of `2`, for a total of `10` columns. From here, you would **offset** by `1` on the left. Considering you now have a total of `11`, you've automatically also offset by `1` on the right.

This can be demonstrated in the following:

```css
.row {
  margin: 0 !important; /* Prevent scrollbars in the fiddle */
  text-align: center; /* Helps illustrate the centralisation */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-1">One</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">Two</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">Three</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">Four</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">Five</div>
</div>
```

If you're not happy with this offset, then you **can** simply make use of a custom media query such as `width: calc(100% / 5)` ...though this would completely violate the point of using Bootstrap; another framework might be more suitable :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice answer, but I don't really like this offset nor change framework only for this thing... Hmmm, give 2 minutes, I will edit my question to add an idea that probably will considered as a "dirty-fix"

Comment: Like I say, you can always craft a custom media query to handle a specific breakpoint, setting `width` to `20%` (or `calc(100% / column-count)`). However, you'd have to account for margins and paddings, and it does kind of go against the 'style' of Bootstrap :)

Comment: That's true, what do you think about of the approach in my question, using JavaScript?