# How to display 5 products in a row, rather than 4 in the "featured" (recommended) module on the main page?

Tags: javascript, php, css, opencart

***For administration:*** *[Five equal columns in twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387740/five-equal-columns-in-twitter-bootstrap/22799354#22799354)
This answer doesn’t work for me because in my case you cannot duplicate  5 times. I suppose the OpenCart "featured" module works with a loop. I don’t understand how to solve my problem that way.*

I configure OpenCart-3 (Bootstrap v3.3.5) on the main page the Featured module is displayed in which there are 10 products. By default, they are displayed in 4 pieces in a row. Total 3 rows are obtained: *4, 4, 2* goods. I need something to be displayed in 2 rows of **5** products.

I found the featured.twig file and the line in it.
Changing ***col-lg-3*** to ***col-lg-2*** I can achieve the display of goods 6 in a row, but I can not understand how to display exactly **5** in a row.

**featured.twig:**

`{% for product in products %}
  <div class="product-layout col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">`

I expect the result to be:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzOxd.png)

but the actual output is:
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vapCJ.png)

Comment: you have to have 5 numbers that add up to 12 (or make your own class that gives it a width of 20%)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22799354/9288348, they explain how to do this in bootstrap 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks solution found**
[*selection-studio*](http://selection-studio.com/5-kolonok-v-bootstrap-4.html)

I had seen similar solutions before, but it worked only the third time. Apparently, I registered styles in the wrong file.
**Thank you.**

[link](http://selection-studio.com/5-kolonok-v-bootstrap-4.html)